# Windows authentication using python

Tags: python, https, python-requests, ntlm-authentication

How to do windows authentication using python.. Any tools to debug ? I tried with request_ntlm, but its not helping. Even i'm not able to get www-authenticate header  from response.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, as it was a problem with client side certificate. As my server will authenticate based on client side certificate and private key.We need to set python Environ variable REQUEST_CA_BUNDLE to .pem certificate and passing client certificate and key along with request, it works. If certificate are properly autheticated then will see www-authenticate header from server.

Comment: Can you please share piece of code for same as I too facing the same issue?

Comment: Do you have .pem certificate. .pem Defined in RFC's 1421 through 1424, this is a container format that may include just the public certificate (such as with Apache installs, and CA certificate files /etc/ssl/certs), or may include an entire certificate chain including public key, private key, and root certificates. Confusingly, it may also encode a CSR (e.g. as used here) as the PKCS10 format can be translated into PEM. The name is from Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM), a failed method for secure email but the container format it used lives on, and is a base64 translation of the x509 ASN.1 keys.

Comment: I am new to this, so its very difficult to understand what you wanted to say

Comment: Go to chrome://settings/ -> advanced->Manage Certificates.  Export the appropriate certificate related to the domain. Once you export that certificate it is .pem